# Create custom Django admin search form

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add some inputs in Django admin's search form.

I override the original template by putting a new template in the related path to origin 'admin/search_form.html'. But when I add a 'select widget' in the new template like: `{{ select_widget }}`. It always be rendered as `<django.forms.widgets.Select object at 0x10f7560d0>`. However, it is rendered as correct html if I invoke its `render()` method.

How can I get the widget be rendered as correct html?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ select_widget.render }}
```

From [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/):

> Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the
>   following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup
> - Attribute lookup
> - Method call
> - List-index lookup

What you need here is the 3rd - method call.

Comment: Thanks. But render takes two arguments: name, value. How can I pass them to it?

Comment: `{{ select_widget.render arg1 arg2 }}`

Comment: `{{ select_widget.render None None }}` will lead to `TemplateSyntaxError` with message `Could not parse the remainder: ' None None' from 'select_widget.render None None'`

Comment: Ops, sorry. Here is an example of passing an argument to method: http://www.diegor.it/2011/04/18/howto-passing-arguments-to-functions-in-django-template/